# Symbol for Sequential Subtraction

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, summation-method

I was just curious that why there is no symbol for sequential subtraction in maths. This is unlike summation and Multiplication? Each having their respective symbols as $\Sigma $ and $\Pi$, namely.

Comment: Are you looking for something to represent $a_1-a_2-a_3-\dots-a_n$? This can just be written $a_1-\sum_{i=2}^n a_i$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: What if we want to subtract negative integers?

Comment: Do you mean if $a_2,...,a_n$ are negative? This works regardless of the values of $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

Comment: You're welcome.